# Check whether an Excel workbook has macros using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to go through hundreds of Excel files to find those that have macros, using a C# client.

I have tried using the code in the accepted answer here:

[Using Interop.Excel to check if Excel file contains VBA Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286289/using-interop-excel-to-check-if-excel-file-contains-vba-macros)

However, this code opens the file first. Many of the files are opening pop up Windows and VBA error messages even after adding `_appExcel.DisplayAlerts = false`

Its also very slow. Is there a better way to go about this, ideally without opening the Excel file first?

I have looked for documentation on MSDN for Excel interop here: [HasVBProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.hasvbproject.aspx) but there are no examples I can work with.

Comment: Are those .XLS or .XLSM ?

Comment: There are XLSM and XLSB files.cheers

Comment: Too bad there are XLSB. XLSM are simply .zip files, you could work directly on that...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
f = Dir("*.xls*")
While f <> ""
On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    If wb.HasVBProject Then
       Debug.Print wb.Name & " has macro"
    Else
        Debug.Print wb.Name & "does not have macro"
    End If
    wb.Close
    f = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this looks like VBA.im using a C# client to enumerate the files.

Answer (score 0):

if workbook events is the problem than you can disable all macros using `Interop.Excel` namespace via `AutomationSecurity` property :

```
MyExcel.Application.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.