# Check if a Excel document has a macro to set correct file extension on save

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, vba

I have a plugin where I download a Excel document from the net and open it.
As the Excel document can be `.xls` or `.xlsx` and the file might contain macros I need to check if the active workbook has macros.

I find a solution but this runs into security problems...

```
var hasMacro = false;
var cmp = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject;
foreach (VBComponent c in from VBComponent c in cmp.VBComponents where c.CodeModule.CountOfLines > 1 select c)
hasMacro = true;
```

But running the code runs into

```
Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted
```

if Excel has not correct properties set in the trust center.

As I do only want to check if a Excel document has macros or not to set the correct file extension to `.xlsm` is there a smarter way to check for macros?

Found this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286289/using-interop-excel-to-check-if-excel-file-contains-vba-macros) but I do not have a property `HasVBProject`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save all files as .xlsm
it won't hurt if it doesn't have a macro

Comment: Doesn't make sense to save if it has no macro. Macros are mostly a security issue these days, so there is a reason a .xlsx file does not contain a macro. .xlsm files provoke additional scans and alerts. So that wouldn't be a proper solution.